# Stopping CompletableFuture with local AtomickBoolean

Tags: java, concurrency

The question may be quite easy, but I would like to make sure that I am doing everything correctly and have not missed any features.

I have a list, I need to divide it into smaller lists and process them in parallel (send to kafka). If an error occurs during processing, all processing must be interrupted. For this I use `AtomicBoolean` flag. Is it correct to use it in this case? Will all running `CompletableFuture` see its values?
Perhaps there are some other ways to solve this problem?

```
    void listen(List<String> records)  {
        List<List<Record>> batches = splitIntoBatches(records, BATCH_SIZE);

        List<CompletableFuture<List<Record>>> futures = new ArrayList<>();

        AtomicBoolean cancel = new AtomicBoolean(false);

        for (List<Record> subBatch : batches) {
            CompletableFuture<List<Record>> future = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
                int current = 0;
                try {
                    for (int i = 0; i < subBatch.size() && !cancel.get(); i++, current++) {
                        //work
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    cancel.set(true);
                    log.error(e);
                }
                return subBatch.subList(current, subBatch.size());
            });

            futures.add(future);
        }

        List<List<Record>> result = CompletableFuture.allOf(futures.toArray(new CompletableFuture[0]))
                .thenApply(v -> futures.stream()
                        .map(CompletableFuture::join)
                        .collect(Collectors.toList()))
                .join();
        //...
    }
```

Comment: Not terribly unreasonable for an early-out, just know that some tasks may not immediately halt (they have to get back to that `cancel.get()` check), so you might also benefit checking mid-loop. Note that the method `CompletableFuture#cancel` exists, and can even call an interrupt on the thread. In this sense, you could cancel the other futures when you hit an exception.

Comment: @Rogue Unfortunately it won't interrupt: `@param mayInterruptIfRunning this value has no effect in this implementation because interrupts are not used to control processing.`

Comment: My question is: do CompletableFutures work with a common AtomicBoolean or does everyone have their own copy?

Comment: You create only one `AtomicBoolean cancel` and all `CompleteableFuture`s reference that single `AtomicBoolean`. Why should there be copies of it? You don't create copies, and Java doesn't create copies behind the scences.